# JBoss/Keycloak Server: Update self-signed Server SSl certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, jboss, keycloak

I am managing a keycloak server that runs as a jboss/keycloak image on a synology nas. The keycloak server is configured to use self-signed ssl certificate (signed with our root certificate).
Now, I created a new root certifacte and signed new server certificates (with openssl). I renamed the server certificate and keyfile to tls.crt and tls.key and uploaded these files to a folder (ssl-Folder) on the nas. The ssl-Folder is mounted in the jboss/keycloak docker image via the docker-compose.yml file:
volumes:

> -ssl-Folder:/etc/x509/https

I restarted the jboss/keycloak docker-container via the terminal command
sudo docker restart
Additionally, I restarted the nas hosting the container.

If I login the running jboss/keycloak docker-container via portainer I can see that the new tls.crt and tls.key files are available within the running container at the path /etc/x509/https and that they are readable for user/group/other. According to jboss/keycloak user guide https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/ 1 (Section “Setting up TLS (SSL)”): “The image will automatically convert them into a Java keystore and reconfigure Wildfly to use it”

However, if I open the address of the keycloak-server in my browser window it is shown that the connection is secured with the old ssl-certificate. It seems to me that the keystore is not updated automatically.

I further connected to the keycloak admin console and deleted the user/realm/keys cache (Master -> Realm Settings -> Cache). Still the new certificate is not used by the server.

What do I have to do to make the server use the new ssl-certificates?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The script `/opt/jboss/tools/x509.sh` is designed to run only once for a newly created container. If you change/update your certificate and just restart the container or just re-run the `x509.sh` script, it won't work. You'll have to destroy the container and create a new one. This way, it'll work ootb.

Comment: Exactly. Even the `docker restart` command didn't work. Had to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same exact issue.. although I'm not using docker compose, I'm spawning a keycloak container and supplying the tls.crt and tls.key files as volumes. Double check in the keycloak container that the two files are indeed files and not **directories**. My problem was that I wasn't providing the absolute path to the files; I was providing relative paths which was causing them to be directories in the container. After I made this change, I saw that the https-keystore.jks and https-keystore.pk12 key stores were created in /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keystores.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the new tls.crt and tls.key files into /etc/x509/https directory, you need to execute /opt/jboss/tools/x509.sh script in order for the new keystore to be generated into /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keystores directory.

Comment: Tried this `/opt/jboss/tools/x509.sh` is designed to run only once during container start.